# counter example in $R$-modules law

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $K$, $L$ and $N$ submodules. I would like to find a counterexample to the equality

> $$N\cap (K+L) =(N\cap K)+(N\cap L)$$

I can prove the equality is true when $K \subset N$.
I.e., what $N,K,L$ exist such that
...

Comment: Alex, if you wish, I think it would be acceptable to post in your own language in addition to English. Also, I don't understand what \coh is supposed to be. Is it set difference?

Comment: Im sorry.$\{1,2\}\coh \{2,3\}=\{2\}$

Comment: Try \cap for intersection.

Comment: It's not clear what your assumption is, and what you wish to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try three lines through the origin in $\mathbf{R}^2$.